# How to measure TCP connection time in Linux

Tags: performance, tcp

I want to measure the overhead in creating a TCP connection.

I know of many tools like `hping` and `netperf`, but they seem oriented at measuring latency.

I want to know how long the 3-way handshake takes, and allocating any buffers, etc., and then closing it. So I want to open a real, legitimate TCP connection, and then close it.

Are there any tools that will do that and help me measure performance?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're asking is some way of measuring the time it takes from the first SYN packet to the first non-zero payload packet on a TCP connection?

Tcpdump is a useful tool in this regard and Theo Schlossnagle has [written](http://www.circonus.com/understanding-service-latencies-via-tcp-analysis/) how this can be achieved. I've used the technique he described to good effect.

Comment: Closing the connection too, but yes.

Answer (score 0):

For simple cases `curl` using the `-w` option can print the time these operations took.

Curl only prints times cumulative from the start, so you have to subtract the numbers yourself. Since the tcp connection only starts after the dns lookup (assuming no redirects) you would have to calculate `time_connect - time_namelookup`. I'm not sure how curl exactly measures time when follwing redirects. Note that this also works also on non-web services because curl will only discover that it's not http after the tcp connection has been established.

Example command:

```
$ curl -s -o /dev/null -w "dns:%{time_namelookup}, redir:%{time_redirect}, tcp:{time_connect}\n" poohl.de
dns:0.046345, redir:0.000000, tcp:0.067986
```

So the time to establish the tcp connection was `0.067986s - 0.046345s = 0.021641s`.

From the manpage:

```
time_appconnect
    The time, in seconds, it took from the start until the SSL/SSH/etc connect/handshake to the remote host was completed.
time_connect
    The time, in seconds, it took from the start until the TCP connect to the remote host (or proxy) was completed.
time_namelookup
    The time, in seconds, it took from the start until the name resolving was completed.
time_pretransfer
    The  time,  in seconds, it took from the start until the file transfer was just about to begin. This includes all pre-transfer commands and negotiations that are specific to the particular protocol(s) involved.
time_redirect
    The time, in seconds, it took for all redirection steps including name lookup, connect, pretransfer and transfer before the final transaction was  started. time_redirect shows the complete execution time for multiple redirections.
time_starttransfer
    The  time, in seconds, it took from the start until the first byte was just about to be transferred. This includes time_pretransfer and also the time the server needed to calculate the result.
time_total
    The total time, in seconds, that the full operation
```